# Payment Options only show up when logged in as admin

Tags: civicontribute

I have two payment processors set up. One for credit card and the other for electronic check. When I am logged in as admin I see the payment processor section and it will allow me to choose one or the other. But when I am not logged in as admin, I do not get those options, but just the credit card section shows up. Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Comment: Is electronic check payment processor derived from an extension? Can you also add CiviCRM version and CMS name?

Comment: Yes it is the Authorize.net eCheck.Net  extension.  I am using Civicrm version 4.7.22 with Wordpress.